# Android Things NTP server

Tags: time, ntp, android-things

I am looking for a way to get the current time in Android Things trough an other NTP.
I can't find a `gps.conf`on Android Things, like it is in normal Android.

Comment: welcome to SO!, please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can use this android library to get current time from NTP servers of your choosing.

```
https://github.com/instacart/truetime-android
```